# Buildstops not creating file with exec in node js

Tags: node.js, sphinx

I'm running two commands

```
indexer idx_name --rotate
indexer idx_name --buildstops dict_file 10
```

Everything is fine when I run these commands from command line. However, when I pass these two commands through my node application using **exec**, first command works successfully and for second command the dict_file is not getting generated.

I tried some combinations with sudo, but it didn't help. I checked the **stdout** from both these ways(node and shell) and it looked same.

Here is my node js code:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var cmd = 'indexer idx_name --rotate && indexer idx_name --buildstops dict_file 10';
exec(cmd, function(err, stdout, stderr) {
   console.log(stdout);
});
```

Is there something I'm missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which ever user is running node, will need permission to write `dict_file`.

Might even find it easier to delete the file, and let it be created by the right user via node (assuming that user can write the the folder)

Sudo could also work, but will need to make sure the user running node, has sudo permissions. Sorting that is definitly outside the remit of stackoverflow.

... do also check you looking in the right place. In your example you dont show a path, so the file `dict_file` will just be created in the current working directory (not sure how node configures that)

Comment: thanks barry, I was looking at the wrong place. Passing path along with dict_file fix the problem